# How to use 2 twig template for for one field (or how to add a variable to a template from a template)

Tags: theming, 8

Let say I have a node template which is calling twice the same field like the following:

```
...
{# First call #}
{{ content.my_field }}
...
{# Second call #}
{{ content.my_field }}
...
```

I also have a preprocessing function which is adding VAR1 and VAR2 to the 'my_field' array like the following:

```
function mymod_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['element'])) {
    $fn=$element['#field_name'];
    if ($fn=='my_field'){
      $vars['VAR1'] = 'a value';
      $vars['VAR2'] = 'another value';
    }
  }
}
```

I would like that the first call of 'My_field' use the default twig template and the 'VAR1' value... As you can imagine, I could do it as this is the normal way Drupal is working.
But I didn't success to make use of an alternate twig template for the second call (and also, I would like this second template use 'VAR2')

My first idea was to put the following just before the first call:

`{{ set content.my_field.is_first_call = true }}`

and to use **only** the default template (I mean not 2 templates) with something like

```
{% if is_first_call %}
  ... code to print the first call
{% else %}
  ... code to print the second call
{% endif %}
```

But I couldn't succeed to transmit a value (is_first_call) from the node template to the default my_field template

**Final note**: I have added the 'VAR1/VAR2' story because I have also tested the `{{ content.my_field | without ('a_check_var')}}` filter: the idea was to remove `a_check_var` from the array to use a construct like `{% if a_check_var %}` in the default template.
Unfortunately, my preprocess function which is adding 'VAR1/VAR2' runs after the `without` filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to add a variable to the field template from the node template?**

What you see in the node template from the field is before the field preprocess is run.

The global preprocess for fields starts like this:

```
function template_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  // Creating variables for the template.
  $variables['entity_type'] = $element['#entity_type'];
  $variables['field_name'] = $element['#field_name'];
  $variables['field_type'] = $element['#field_type'];
  $variables['label_display'] = $element['#label_display'];
```

Here can see, how the variables for the field template are built.

**Example:**

To add a variable in node set the variable with a '#' prefix:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['content']['my_field'])) {
    $variables['content']['my_field']['#var1'] = 'a value';
  }
}
```

And then in the field template:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) { 
  if (isset($variables['element']['#var1'])) {
    $variables['var1'] = $variables['element']['#var1'];
  }
}
```

The variable is then available in the field twig:

```
{{ var1 }}
```

To solve your specific problem I would suggest you copy the field in node preprocess and then set for both copies different variables.

Comment: Many thanks! I could succeed by moving the code from my preprocess_field function to my preprocess_node function. This is not what you have explained, but your proposal was working and give me the idea to do so. This is why I validated it.

Comment: Great, the example is about the idea how node and field template work together. Then there are a lot of things you can do with this.